work / be working

#1 I wouldn't work here if I didn't enjoy my job.


#2 I wouldn't be working here if I didn't enjoy my job.

I think the are exactly the same meaning, but I'm not sure. Is there any difference?

Very close, but not exactly the same.

There is a nuanced difference.  The continuous "working" has the sense of work-in-progress and is more actual than simple "work"; the inverse is that simple "work" is a shade less actual, and is a shade more abstract.

I wouldn't work here if I didn't enjoy my job.

Paraphrase:
I wouldn't choose to work here if I didn't the enjoy my job [here].

I wouldn't be working here if I didn't enjoy my job.

Paraphrase:
I wouldn't be doing this work here if I didn't enjoy my job.

I'd use wouldn't be working but would use wouldn't work in a context where  the speaker is not already working there:
I wouldn't work here even if I was offered a post.
Edit
As commented, it would also be perfectly possible to use wouldn't work when the speaker currently works there.

You might not, but it would be perfectly possible to use wouldn't work when the speaker currently works there.

Thanks, @Kate Bunting.  Okay, I've added this point to my answer.
